# Как не давать процессу запускаться в Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, производительность, процесс

Я пишу программу для ускорения компьютера на C++. Одной из ее функций будет закрытие фоновых процессов по выбору. Но проблема в том, что некоторые процессы снова запускаются. Есть ли способ заблокировать запуск процесса (удаление         исполняемого файла не предлагать)?
P.S. Все время следить, не запустился ли процесс снова, и выгружать его - не     вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перезапуск работает через службы Windows, либо через планировщик заданий.
Соответственно, надо просмотреть оба места и изменить правило.

Далее, прибивать процесс - это вообще не очень хорошо. Для служб лучше выполнить команду stop и изменить способ запуска, чтобы предотвратить запуск при следующих загрузках. Для планировщика лучше отключить соответствующие задания для следующих загрузок. И лучше делать это всё перед выключением компьютера, чтобы на момент включения всё лишнее уже было отключено.

Answer (score 1):

Перехватывайте системную функцию  [NtCreateSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx)().

[Hooking the native API and controlling process creation on a system-wide basis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11985/Hooking-the-native-API-and-controlling-process-cre)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю радикальный способ. Создать пустой exe-заглушку, который не будет ничего делать, тупо висеть в вечном Sleep. И прописывать его процессам-жертвам в качестве отладчика в [Image File Execution Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(VS.71).aspx).

Это гарантированно позволяет подменить запуск процесса-жертвы своим процессом. В случае с сервисом могут быть проблемы - система будет ждать от него ответа и перезапускать (перезапуская "отладчик"). Но для всего остального - жутко эффективно.

И, кстати, это же является эффективным способом отладить старт сервиса в production-окружении - когда сервис уже установлен, Debugger.Launch в код OnStart вписать уже нельзя, а запустить сервис как консольку - тоже.

Comment: Обязательное чтение по данному вопросу: [walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) (читать вместе с комментариями).

Comment: @VladD какой вопрос - такой и ответ :)

Comment: @VladD вообще я написал ответ только ради упоминания о возможности отладить старт сервиса. А в целом - сама по себе идея "запрещать запуск процесса" - жесточайший костыль.

Comment: Угу, я именно это и хотел сказать. (Ну и сам текст на мой вкус смешной и в кассу.) Дополнительное чтение адресовано больше не вам, а автору вопроса. Ваш ответ очень уж в сторону «highest ladder».

Comment: (ЗЫ: «Жесточайший» — это цитата из нового-старого президента?)

Comment: @VladD да. даже странно что президент может так эффективно зафорсить личный мем